How to simplify xml so it isn't so long in the <BuildVerification> tag area
I have an xml config file and with all the processes I'm including, it makes my xml file over 1000 lines long.  My team is complaining that the size of the file makes it tough to update.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to shorten/simplify the xml document?
This is what the xml format looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BuildVerficationRoot>
<Configuration>
    <Value Name="emailFrom">SCM-BuildCoordinator@co.com</Value>
    <Value Name="admin_list">me@co.com</Value> 
    <Value Name="distribution_list">people@co.com</Value> 
    <Value Name="SmtpMailClient">info.co.net</Value>
    <Value Name="verboseLogFileName">VerifyBuildVerbose.txt</Value>
    <Value Name="statsLogProcessVerFileName">Stats.txt</Value>
    <Value Name="project">proj</Value>
    <Value Name="version">1.0</Value>
    <Value Name="publishHeader">PublishDestination</Value>
</Configuration>
<BuildVerification>
    <codeFreezeTime>19:00</codeFreezeTime>
    <build>
        <BuildMachine>mach-1</BuildMachine>
            <Process>
                <ProcessName>Version</ProcessName>
                <startTimeHeader>StartTime</startTimeHeader>
                <endTimeHeader>EndTime</endTimeHeader>
                <failureColumns>ErrorDescription</failureColumns>
                    <Conditions>
                        <Condition
                            name='VersionFile' value="\view\dev\Retail\filename.cs">
                        </Condition>
                    </Conditions>
                    <SuccessCriteria>
                        <field>Status</field>
                        <comparison>equal</comparison>
                        <value>Success</value>
                    </SuccessCriteria>
            </Process>
<!--there are several build machines and each build machine has several processes under it, so this is what is many many lines -->
    </build>
</BuildVerification>
</BuildVerficationRoot>

The way my program works, is that it reads the xml file using LINQ, and reads log files into a dataTable, and I iterate over the Lists storing the LINQ, and compare with data in the log files to determine if the builds were successful.
Looking for simplified xml, that is fewer lines.
For more info on this project, like classes used to store the info that is referred to in the LINQ, see classes for LINQ.
The area of xml that needs shortening is in the  tag, which is very long.  It works perfectly, just the team thinks the xml is too long so it's unwieldy. We don't want to use a format to store the data other than xml, just want to make the xml more compact.
I saw xml minifier, but it just appears to remove line breaks so it's all horribly formatted.

Determining how to remove/modify something other than whitespace would require knowing what tags/data can be modified or removed, which no one here is in a position to decide.

You could save a lot of lines by using attributes instead of nodes. That way, you are flatten the structure. Keep in mind, that you have to change your code that reads the xml. Maybe you could use a xml serializer to read the xml. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BuildVerification>
    <Config emailFrom="SCM-BuildCoordinator@co.com" 
            adminList="me@co.com" 
            distributionList="people@co.com" 
            SmtpMailClient="info.co.net" 
            verboseLogFileName="VerifyBuildVerbose.txt" 
            statsLogProcessVerFileName="Stats.txt" 
            project="proj" 
            version="1.0" 
            publishHeader="PublishDestination" />
    <CodeFreeze time="19:00" />
    <Build machine="mach-1">
        <Process name="Version" 
                 startTimeHeader="StartTime" 
                 endTimeHeader="EndTime" 
                 failureColumns="ErrorDescription">
            <Condition name="VersionFile" value="\view\dev\Retail\filename.cs" />
            <SuccessCriteria field="Status" comparison="equal" value="Success" />
        </Process>
    </Build>
</BuildVerification>

Also, you could remove default values. For example if the failureColumns is often ErrorDescription you could set this in your code as default if it is not declared in the xml. That could work with all values in your xml.

That might be doable.  Thanks Sebastian.  I might be able to remove failureColumns where the log table doesn't have a failure indication, but it varies greatly in column names, and sometimes has multiple column names.

the reason I had the conditions was for cases I have multiple conditions, which I do have a couple of.  Same thing for success criteria, which I might have multiples of.
